# subset of space is complete if space is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Given that $C[-\pi,\pi]$ is complete:
How can we prove, by using the supremum norm, that the space:

$$C_p[-\pi,\pi]=\{f\in C[-\pi,\pi]\mid f(-\pi)=f(\pi)\}$$

is also complete? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f_n)$ a cauchy sequence in $C_p[-\pi,\pi]$. Denote $f$ its limit. Then $$|f(-\pi)-f(\pi)|\leq |f(-\pi)-f_n(-\pi)|+\underbrace{|f_n(-\pi)-f_n(\pi)|}_{=0}+|f_n(\pi)-f(\pi)|$$
$$\leq 2\sup_{x\in [-\pi,\pi]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

The claim follow.

Comment: I'm not sure that I got you. could you please show how to continue?

Comment: @ASH: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Try showing the subspace is closed.